# PostGIS: Function for Selecting Points in a Polygon

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis, postgresql-8.4

I've been banging on this for a few hours, but since I'm relatively new to PostgreSQL and PostGIS, I can't find the solution.  I'm trying to create a stored procedure (function) which will return all locations whose specified point geometry is within the specified polygon.

Here is my PostgreSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.spGeoPoly(polystring text) RETURNS setof locations
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT * FROM locations
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((polystring))', 4326), point_geom);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I've tested this with a hard-coded polystring, which works, but as a function with an input string such as:

```
SELECT spGeoPoly('50.4 8.2,50.3 9.3,49.9 9.5,49.7 8.8,49.9 7.8,50.4 8.2');
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "polygon((" <-- parse error at position 9 within geometry
```

I assume my input text is not getting transformed properly into the format necessary to create the polygon, since position 9 is the start of the polygon parameter string.  How can I fix the text parameter?

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4.13 and PostGIS 1.5.8.

Comment: Guessing... should it be `WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(('+polystring+'))', 4326), point_geom);` ?

Comment: That's not it unfortunately, I'm getting `ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown + text`

Comment: Does PostGres use || instead of +  for joining strings? :)

Comment: Yep!  I knew it was something simple :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you already know this is a simple fix.  I am writing to explain the fix.

Your function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.spGeoPoly(polystring text) RETURNS setof locations
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT * FROM locations
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((polystring))', 4326), point_geom);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The troublesome part is:

```
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((polystring))', 4326)
```

What this is telling PostgreSQL to do is take the string `Polygon((polystring))` and pass it in to the  first argument of the `ST_GeomFromText` function.  This is of course not what you mean.  You want to construct the polygon using the value of `polystring.`

To correct this simply concatenate the string:

```
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((' || polystring || '))', 4326)
```

Then PostgreSQL will be happy.